# PowerShell Returning Multiple WMI Object Values From A Function

Tags: function, powershell, object

I'm creating a function to pull back basic drive information from a supplied server name. In the function I want to pull back the drive letter, free space, total space and a percentage free. I'm struggling with the return object and how to return multiple values. I don't get the drive letter I am expecting.  For drive letter I get something like @(DeviceID=C:) or I get a long string for the drive letter that looks like a UNC. How do I pass back multiple values as an object from the function? (My PowerShell experience is about 1 month)

Code

```
function Get-DiskPercentFree ($serverName){

$diskinfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $($serverName)  -Filter DriveType=3 | Select-Object $($serverName), DeviceID, @{'Name'='Size (GB)'; 'Expression'={[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB)}}, @{'Name'='Freespace (GB)'; 'Expression'={[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1GB)}}, @{'Name'='Percent Free'; 'Expression'={[math]::round(($_.freespace / $_.size) * 100)}} | Format-Table;

new-object psobject -property  @{Server = $($serverName); Drive = $($_.DeviceID)}
}
Get-DiskPercentFree("DevServerName")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, be careful with the `Format` cmdlets. They should only be used at the very end and not saved in a variable.

Your `New-Object` cmdlet also doesn't reference your `$diskinfo` variable. So `$_.DeviceID` would be undefined because nothing is passed down the pipeline.

Also the extra sub-expression operators are unnecessary `$()`.

I personally like the `[pscustomobject]` type accelerator over using `New-Object` as it's more readable.

```
function Get-DiskPercentFree {

    [CmdletBinding(ConfirmImpact = 'Low')]
    param (
        [string]$ServerName
    )

    $DiskInfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $($ServerName)  -Filter DriveType=3

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'ServerName'     = $ServerName
        'DeviceID'       = $DiskInfo.DeviceID
        'Size (GB)'      = [math]::Truncate($DiskInfo.Size / 1GB)
        'Freespace (GB)' = [math]::Truncate($DiskInfo.FreeSpace / 1GB)
        'Percent Free'   = [math]::Round(($DiskInfo.FreeSpace / $DiskInfo.Size) * 100)
    }
}

Get-DiskPercentFree "DevServerName"
```

Lastly, have you tried the `Get-Volume` cmdlet?

Comment: No, I have not tried the Get-Volume cmdlet. Let me give this a try and see.